# Configuring a Spring Cloud Data Flow Task with its own Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a task application with its own database that I'd like to run in Spring Cloud Data Flow.

My problem is that SCDF overwrites the datasource configuration in the task with the datasource configuration for SCDF. (Both databases are Oracle DBs.)

My task should write to a different database (but I also want to know its status in SCDF database).

How is it possible to configure my task to connect to its own database as well as to SCDF's database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

I defined both data sources in a configuration class (one for JPA and one for SCDF) following this as an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

However this wasn't enough because the Data Flow Server accepts only one data source by default. To overcome this, one needs to extend the `DefaultTaskConfigurer` and set the Data Flow Server's data source in the constructor.

```
@Component
public class GeneratorTaskConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {

    public GeneratorTaskConfigurer(@Qualifier("dataflowDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer needs more visibility. Lots of now-obsolete/incomplete answers regarding this topic.

Comment: @S0m30n3 - can you give us the full example code?

Answer (score 3):

You can have one config class with SCDF datasource code like this

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class MySqlConfiguration {

@Bean
public Cloud cloud() {
    return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return cloud().getSingletonServiceConnector(DataSource.class, null);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepositoryFactoryBean() throws Exception{
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTaskConfigurer defaultTaskConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(dataSource());
}
}
```

And then have your other datasource configuration in a separate class for the database you want to write to.
Make sure you mark the SCDF one @Primary, otherwise you get multiple datasource error.

Hope this helps.